# Is it mandatory to lock mutex before signaling on condition variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

We have implemented TaskRunner whose functions will be called by different threads to start, stop and post tasks. TaskRunner will internally create a thread and if the queue is not empty, it will pop the task from queue and executes it. Start() will check if the thread is running. If not creates a new thread. Stop() will join the thread. The code is as below.

```
bool TaskRunnerImpl::PostTask(Task* task) {
  tasks_queue_.push_back(task);
  return true;
}

void TaskRunnerImpl::Start() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(is_running_mutex_);
  if(is_running_) {
    return;
  }
  is_running_ = true;

  runner_thread_ = std::thread(&TaskRunnerImpl::Run, this);
}

void TaskRunnerImpl::Run() {
  while(is_running_) {
    if(tasks_queue_.empty()) {
      continue;
    }
    Task* task_to_run = tasks_queue_.front();
    task_to_run->Run();
    tasks_queue_.pop_front();

    delete task_to_run;
  }
}

void TaskRunnerImpl::Stop() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(is_running_mutex_);
  is_running_ = false;
  if(runner_thread_.joinable()) {
    runner_thread_.join();
  }
}
```

We want to use conditional variables now otherwise the thread will be continuously checking whether the task queue is empty or not. We implemented as below.

- Thread function (Run()) will wait on condition variable.
- PostTask() will signal if some one posts a task.
- Stop() will signal if some one calls stop.

Code is as below.

```
bool TaskRunnerImpl::PostTask(Task* task) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> taskGuard(m_task_mutex);
  tasks_queue_.push_back(task);
  m_task_cond_var.notify_one();
  return true;
}

void TaskRunnerImpl::Start() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(is_running_mutex_);
  if(is_running_) {
    return;
  }
  is_running_ = true;

  runner_thread_ = std::thread(&TaskRunnerImpl::Run, this);
}

void TaskRunnerImpl::Run() {
    while(is_running_) {
        Task* task_to_run = nullptr;

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(m_task_mutex);
            m_task_cond_var.wait(mlock, [this]() {
                return !(is_running_ && tasks_queue_.empty());
            });

            if(!is_running_) {
                return;
            }

            if(!tasks_queue_.empty()) {
                task_to_run = tasks_queue_.front();
                task_to_run->Run();
                tasks_queue_.pop_front();
            }
        }

        if(task_to_run)
            delete task_to_run;
    }
}

void TaskRunnerImpl::Stop() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(is_running_mutex_);
    is_running_ = false;
    m_task_cond_var.notify_one();
    if(runner_thread_.joinable()) {
        runner_thread_.join();
    }
}
```

I have couple of questions as below. Can some one please help me to understand these.

1. Condition variable m_task_cond_var is linked with mutex m_task_mutex. But Stop() already locks mutex is_running_mutex to gaurd 'is_running_'. Do I need to lock m_task_mutex before signaling? Here I am not convinced why to lock m_task_mutex as we are not protecting any thing related to task queue.
2. In Thread function(Run()), we are reading is_running_ without locking is_running_mutex. Is this correct?

Comment: 1: you need to lock the mutex to update the queue, but it is not necesary to keep the lock to signal: check example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait
2: the use of is_running is unprotected, I would presume that this code will work in x64 architecture, but could have problems somewhere else. I recommend checking jthread and stop_token for this purpose, will help you having a less convoluted loop.

Comment: Not directly your question but when performing `task_to_run->Run()`, `m_task_mutex` is still locked, which prevents from posting other tasks. Is it really what you want?

Comment: @prog-fh : Thank you for pointing this. I will change my code.

Comment: It is not clear why you need additional mutex for running flag, one mutex would be just fine and make things simpler.

Comment: Your `Run` function accesses `is_running_` without holding the mutex that protects it. That's UB and makes the code's behavior impossible to analyze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to lock `m_task_mutex` before signaling [In `Stop`]?

When the predicate being tested in `condition_variable::wait` method depends on something happening in the signaling thread (which is almost always), then you should obtain the mutex before signaling. Consider the following possibility if you are **not** holding the `m_task_mutex`:

1. The watcher thread (`TaskRunnerImpl::Run`) wakes up (via spurious wakeup or being notified from elsewhere) and obtains the mutex.
2. The watcher thread checks its predicate and sees that it is `false`.
3. The signaler thread (`TaskRunnerImpl::Stop`) changes the predicate to return `true` (by setting `is_running_ = false;`).
4. The signaler thread signals the condition variable.
5. The watcher thread waits to be signaled (bad)

   - the signal has already come and gone
   - the predicate was `false`, so the watcher begins waiting, possibly indefinitely.

The worst that can happen if you are holding the mutex when you signal is that, the blocked thread (`TaskRunnerImpl::Run`) wakes up and is immediately blocked when trying to obtain the mutex. This can have some performance implications.

---

> In [`TaskRunnerImpl::Run`] , we are reading `is_running_` without locking `is_running_mutex`. Is this correct?

In general no. Even if it's of type `bool`. Because a boolean is typically implemented as a single byte, it's possible that one thread is writing to the byte while you are reading, resulting in a partial read. In *practice*, however, it's safe. That said, you should obtain the mutex before you read (and then release immediately afterwards).

In fact, it may be preferable to use `std::atomic<bool>` instead of a `bool` + `mutex` combination (or `std::atomic_flag` if you want to get fancy) which will have the same effect, but be easier to work with.

Comment: "You do not need to obtain the same mutex that a condition variable is waiting on before signaling it. " Actually you do.

Comment: @Slava: Perhaps I was unclear? The signaller does not need to obtain the mutex, but when waiting on a condition variable the mutex should be held before calling `wait`

Comment: No you were clear. If you change watched variable and signal without or before locking the mutex condition variable is used with you will be exposed to race condition - you can miss the notification.

Comment: @Slava: You are referring to the scenario where spurious wakeup might happen while the watched variable is being altered?

Comment: No, you lock mutex, then check condition under it and go to sleep and unlock atomically. That the hole purpose of condition variable and how it suppose to work. Otherwise if you signal it before mutex locked (or mutex never locked) it can wake up check that condition was not met yet, go to sleep again and then first thread would change the condition. So your signal is missed.

Comment: @Slava: It's always possible to miss a notification on a condition variable. That's why predicate based condition variables are preferred; the implementation will check the predicate before blocking. The one scenario where you need to worry about locking the mutex before signaling the condition variable is when spurious wakeup on the blocked thread might result in a partial read.

Comment: " It's always possible to miss a notification on a condition variable." Sorry I did not make myself clear, you may miss notification on condition variable, that is fine. But in your scenario you may miss condition you are waiting for, and that is a disaster. You can easily end up on setting  `running` flag `false` but worker thread waiting indefinately.

Comment: @Slava unless the compiler performs reordering to place the signal before the assignment (and if we use `atomic<bool>` it won't), then I don't see how it's possible for the blocked thread to miss the notification. If the blocked thread is actually the first to obtain the mutex and check the predicate before the signalling thread, there's nothing you can do in this case anyway; it's always possible for that to happen. If you want to enforce that the blocking thread does not get to this scenario first, you need a barrier, which can be simulated with another condition variable.

Comment: "unless the compiler performs reordering to place the signal before the assignment (and if we use atomic<bool> it won't)" No, it may happen without reordering.  Watching thread wakes due to whatever reason, checks this flag (it did not happen yet) and havent go to sleep on condition variable yet. Now signalling thread changes bool and signals. Watching thread will miss it because it already checked flag but it would not receive signal either, as it is not waiting on condition variable yet. Atomicity of going to sleep and unlocking the mutex is specially created to avoid this scenario.

Comment: @Slava: That makes sense. To rephrase what you said. 1. The watcher thread wakes up and obtains the mutex. 2. The watcher thread checks its predicate and sees that it is `false`. 3. The signaler thread changes the predicate to return `true`. 4. The signaler thread signals the condition variable. 5. The watcher thread waits to be signaled (bad)
--- Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, basically the system guarantees that signal on condition variable happened **after** mutex unlocked by `wait()` will be delivered. To guarantee that you send signal **after** you have to change condition under the same mutex and signal during mutex locked or after unlocked, not before.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to lock `m_task_mutex` before signaling [In `Stop`]?

Yes you do. You must change condition under the same mutex and send signal either after the mutex is locked or unlocked after the change. If you do not use the same mutex, or send signal before that mutex is locked you create race condition that `std::condition_variable` is created to solve.

Logic is this:

Watching thread locks mutex and checks watched condition. If it did not happen it goes to sleep and unlocks the mutex **atomically**. So signaling thread lock the mutex, change condition and signal. If signalling thread does that before watching one locks the mutex, then watchiong one would see condition happen and would not go to sleep. If it locks before, it would go to sleep and woken when signalling thread raise the signal.

Note: you can signal condition variable before or after mutex is unlocked, both cases is correct but may affect performance. But it is incorrect to signal before locking the mutex.

> Condition variable m_task_cond_var is linked with mutex m_task_mutex. But Stop() already locks mutex is_running_mutex to gaurd 'is_running_'. Do I need to lock m_task_mutex before signaling? Here I am not convinced why to lock m_task_mutex as we are not protecting any thing related to task queue.

You overcomlicated your code and made things worse. You should use only one mutex in this case and it would work as intended.

> In Thread function(Run()), we are reading is_running_ without locking is_running_mutex. Is this correct?

On x86 hardware it may "work", but from language point of view this is UB.